# Perl ServerCommon module is missing in perl windows

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module, strawberry-perl, activeperl

I'm using Active perl version 5.22  on windows  , When I try to execute a program it says serverCommon.pm is missing , you need to install serverCommon module   but I couldn't find a module with the same name from internet, I tried the same for strawberry perl also.

please some one help ,me to resolve this issue .

here is my perl code

```
use ServerCommon;

$buffer = <<_OUT
CN=""
Domain=""
OU=""
Organization=""
ID=""
_OUT
;



%args = ServerCommon::GenHashFromBuffer($buffer);



Search(%args); # this function is implemented by myself for searching
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which module you are using in your code? Better to show you code.

Comment: Why are you using `ServerCommon`? Is it a module you wrote? Are you working on someone else's code? If so, you should ask the people who wrote that code.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you will find that accuracy is important in programming. In your description you call the module "serverCommon", but in your code it is "ServerCommon". The difference in case is important.

Most Perl modules are distributed on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/). But it looks like [your missing module isn't there](https://metacpan.org/search?q=servercommon&size=20&search_type=modules). In fact [Google can't find anything useful either](https://www.google.co.uk/?q=perl%20module%20servercommon).

So it seems that your module must be internal to your organisation. Or, perhaps, part of some software package that isn't installed on your computer.

Where did you get the program that uses this module? My best suggestion would be to go back to the person who gave you this code and ask them where you can get this module from.